# Octal, Hex, Unicode

Tags: ruby, unicode, hex, sip, octal

I have a character appearing over the wire that has a hex value and octal value `\xb1` and `\261`.

This is what my header looks like:

```
From: "\261Central Station <sip@...>"
```

Looking at the [ASCII table](http://www.ascii-code.com/) the character in the picture is "`±`":

[image]

What I don't understand:

1. If I try to test the same by passing "`±Central Station`" in the header I see it converted to "`\xC2\xB1`". Why?
2. How can I have "`\xB1`" or "`\261`" appearing over the wire instead of "`\xC2\xB1`".
   e. If I try to print "`\xB1`" or "`\261`" I never see "`±`" being printed. But if I print "`\u00b1`" it prints the desired character, I'm assuming because "`\u00b1`" is the Unicode format.

Comment: We'd like to see the minimum code necessary to demonstrate the problem. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the page you linked to:

> #### The extended ASCII codes (character code 128-255)
>
> There are several different variations of the 8-bit ASCII table. The table below is according to ISO 8859-1, also called ISO Latin-1.

That's worth reading twice. The character codes 128–255 aren't ASCII (ASCII is a 7-bit encoding and ends at 127).

Assuming that you're correct that the character in question is `±` (it's likely, but not guaranteed), your text could be encoded ISO 8850-1 or, as @muistooshort kindly pointed out in the comments, any of a number of other [ISO 8859-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) or [CP-12XX (Windows-12XX)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) encodings. We do know, however, that the text isn't (valid) UTF-8, because `0xb1` on its own isn't a valid UTF-8 character.

If you're lucky, whatever client is sending this text specified the encoding in the [`Content-Type` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-20.15).

As to your questions:

> 1. If I try to test the same by passing `±Central Station` in header I see it get converted to `\xC2\xB1`. Why?

The text you're passing is in UTF-8, and the bytes that represent `±` in UTF-8 are `0xC2 0xB1`.

> 2. How can I have `\xB1` or `\261` appearing over the wire instead of `\xC2\xB1`?

We have no idea how you're testing this, so we can't answer this question. In general, though: Either send the text encoded as ISO 8859-1 (`Encoding::ISO_8859_1` in Ruby), or whatever encoding the original text was in, or as raw bytes (`Encoding::ASCII_8BIT` or `Encoding::BINARY`, which are aliases for each other).

> 2. If I try to print `\xB1` or `\261` I never see `±` being printed. But if I print `\u00b1` it prints the desired character. (I'm assuming because `\u00b1` is the unicode format but I will love If some can explain this in detail.)

That's not a question, but the reason is that `\xB1` (`\261`) is not a valid UTF-8 character. Some interfaces will print `�` for invalid characters; others will simply elide them. `\u00b1`, on the other hand, is a valid Unicode code point, which Ruby knows how to represent in UTF-8.

Brief aside: UTF-8 (like UTF-16 and UTF-32) is a character encoding specified by the Unicode standard. [U+00B1](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b1/index.htm) is the Unicode code point for `±`, and `0xC2 0xB1` are the bytes that represent that code point in UTF-8. In Ruby we can represent UTF-8 characters using either the Unicode code point (`\u00b1`) or the UTF-8 bytes (in hex: `\xC2\xB1`; or octal: `\302\261`, although I don't recommend the latter since fewer Rubyists are familiar with it).

Character encoding is a big topic, well beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer. For a good primer, read Joel Spolsky's ["The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), and for more details on how character encoding works in Ruby read Yehuda Katz's ["Encodings, Unabridged"](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/17/encodings-unabridged/). Reading both will take you less than 30 minutes and will save you hundreds of hours of pain in the future.

Comment: "Character encoding is a big topic". Boy, that's sure true. They opened a can of worms when they decided ASCII wasn't enough. :-)

Comment: The presence of `\xb1` doesn't necessarily mean that it is Latin-1. Most of the ISO-8859-X (all but -6 AFAIK) encodings use `\xb1` for something as do the various CP-12XX encodings from Windows. You need more data and ideally some context to guess the encoding.

Comment: No worries, character encoding is such a big mess with so many standards to choose from. At least we have nearly universal UTF-8 support these days.